# Sorting URLs with FetchRequest crashes when new content is saved

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have an app which uses Core Data with an entity called `Item` and has the attribute "url" to save `URL`.
The FetchRequest looks like the code below.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.url, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
```

The app crashes when creating a item

```
    let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
    newItem.url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") //crashes after this line
    
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
```

with this crash log

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2838187e0'
```

When sorting using other attributes(ex. `String`) doesn't cause the app to crash.

I have also tried implementing fetchrequest from `init()`

```
var fetchedItem: FetchRequest<Item>
init(){
    fetchedItem = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.url, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
}
```

Changing the sort from string to url works, only crashes when creating a new item to save.

Is this a wrong way for implementing? Or is it just not possible to use FetchRequest and Sort by URL together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look closely at the error message

> '-[NSURL compare:]: unrecognized selector sent

and please look also at the [NSSortDescriptor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssortdescriptor?language=objc)

> You construct instances of NSSortDescriptor by specifying the key path of the property to be compared and the order of the sort (ascending or descending). Optionally, you can also specify a selector to use to perform the comparison, which allows you to specify other comparison selectors such as localizedStandardCompare: and localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:. **Sorting raises an exception if the objects to be sorted do not respond to the sort descriptor’s comparison selector**

So the error is obvious: `NSURL` is not comparable. You need a string like `description`, `absoluteString` or just the `host` (the `google.com` part)

---

One solution is to create an extension of `(NS)URL` like in Asperi's answer.

An easier solution is to create the `NSSortDescriptor` with a string key (path) rather than a Swift key path.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "url.host", ascending: true)], animation: .default)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following extension to `URL` (or `NSURL`)

```
extension URL {
    public func compare(_ other: URL) -> ComparisonResult {
        self.absoluteString.compare(other.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

Comment: This extension is intended to be used in the comparator part of the NSSortDescriptor right?